# Inputting file on Mac in CLion.

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I am trying to read a file using C++ in CLion on my Mac. I usually read files on a Windows computer in class, which is a much easier process, but on my Mac it was printing the name of the file instead of the contents of the file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;




//Function Prototypes for reading grades and calculations
void findMaxGrade (double [], double);
void findMinGrade ( double [], double);
void findAverageGrade (double [], double);

const int GRADES = 10; // Array size

int main()
{

double number [GRADES]; //The Array has 10 elements
ifstream inputFileStream;

//Set up file path
string readGrades = ("/home/Lidah/Desktop/grades.txt");

//Store values in the Array
for (int counter = 0; counter < GRADES ; counter++)
{
    number [counter] = counter;
}

// Check if file opened correctly
if (! inputFileStream)
{
    cout << " Unable to open file for reading! ";
    return 1;
}

//read contents of the file
inputFileStream.open (readGrades); //Come back and fix this format!


for (int counter = 0; counter < GRADES; counter++)
{

  cout << readGrades << endl;

}

inputFileStream.close();




return 0;
}


//Define the function
```

Comment: You open `inputFileStream` and then never use it - this does not read the contents of the file on any OS

Comment: You've got some bad habits here you need to kick. One is using C-style fixed length arrays, use `std::vector` instead. Two is a complete lack of indentation. Three is declaring `string x = ("y")` where the brackets aren't necessary. Four is adding spaces where they don't belong, like between function names and arguments, and variables and array brackets.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I'm a student. A complete beginner. MY instructors Programming Style is different from yours when it comes to spaces, and we have yet to learn about vectors. I'm still trying to understand how to handle functions. I have not completed this particular code. I just wanted  information on how to open a file on my Mac using CLion. Thank you.

Comment: Your instructor has a very quirky, highly unusual coding style. I hope you survive this alleged C++ course and can learn how to do C++ properly despite it. As others have pointed out, you need to open the file, not just put the name of some file in a string and hope it magically opens. The [constructor takes a filename argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).

Comment: @tadman Yes, I would agree judging by your comments, which is why I'm here. I want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are not reading the file, but instad you are printing the string with file path. You need to read the input stream, for example:

```
inputFileStream.open(readGrades);

std::string grade;
while (std::getline(inputFileStream, grade)){
    cout << grade;
}
```

Comment: The inputFileStream is already initialized in his code: inputFileStream.open(readGrades);